# Visual Studio 2010 Debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I'm having some problems (as some of you will see from another question I asked) with getting a program I made in Visual Studio 2010 to run on another computer.
My computer is Windows 7 x64
The destination computer is Windows XP x86 (SP2)

I've already checked to see that I'm compiling for x86.

Anyway, my question is: Is there a debugger I can install that will tell me what errors the program is having? Like a .NET Debugger that does not involve me installing Visual Studio 2010 on the destination computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use WinDbg + the SOS extension.  This is a much lighter weight debugger that is easily installable but has a steeper learning curve than Visual Studio.  I often use it though when I need a light weight debugging experience

- WinDbg http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.Mspx
- SOS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx

Comment: +1. I'm a big fan of WinDBG, it's definitely the easiest way to debug when VS or your code aren't at hand. A great tool for all .NET developers in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the client computer when it is running the program, the easiest thing would probably be to [deploy the remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx), and debug the program on your own machine, while it is running on the client PC.

Otherwise, [you can use DbgClr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309371.aspx), which is distrubted with the .NET framework SDK.

Comment: I can't access the computer remotely, as it's not hooked up to a network connection of any kind. I'll have to look into DbgClr

Comment: I can't find DbgClr, where can I get this?

Comment: It can't debug .NET 4.0 programs.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a program like ProcDump to take several snapshot dumps of your program on the remote computer and USB copy them to debug back at your workstation.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

You can save a dump at various triggers like an Unhandled exception. Visual Studio can open the dump back at your workstation and 2010 supports mixed mode debugging.